# Use numpy argmax on the 3rd dimension of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3d numpy array of shape `(150, 9, 5)` and I would like to get the argmax of the 3rd dimension (out of the elements) but I cannot get it done. 
For example, let's say the array looks like (this example does not follow the shape I am using in my code):

```
[[[615, 142, 18]],

   [[12, 412, 98]],

   [[5, 11, 162]],

   [[19, 76, 7]],

   [[56, 78, 12]],

   [[119, 41, 55]],

   [[26, 7, 15]],

   [[19, 67, 53]]]
```

I would like to get back an array of shape (150, 9, 1) (again this is in my case, not related to the example). For the example it would be:

```
[[[0]],

   [[1]],

   [[2]],

   [[1]],

   [[1]],

   [[0]],

   [[0]],

   [[1]]]
```

When I try `np.argmax()` with both `axis 0 and 1`, I get wrong results.

Is there a way to work it out directly or should I go through each (9,5) using a for loop ?

Comment: `ind[...,None]` with `ind` being the argmax indices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got extra axes with extra dimensions:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[[615, 142, 18]],

   [[12, 412, 98]],

   [[5, 11, 162]],

   [[19, 76, 7]],

   [[56, 78, 12]],

   [[119, 41, 55]],

   [[26, 7, 15]],

   [[19, 67, 53]]])

a.argmax(axis=2)
```

Output:

```
Out[82]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [1],
       [1],
       [0],
       [0],
       [1]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! This does the job

Comment: You're welcome! Could you please mark it as the accepted answer so there's no confusion? Thanks !

Comment: Sure I will ! I need to wait some time before I can do that, which is why I haven't yet (SO rules)

Comment: Thanks @Wazaki !